# What does it mean when a package is installed as "non-active development"?

Tags: python, virtualenv, yolk

For whatever reason, my build system isn't installing one of my packages properly.  When I use yolk (from within a virtualenv), I get the following:

```
bin/yolk -l elig
elig            - 3.1.2.dev    - non-active development (/home/jason/src/interface_dev/elig)
```

How exactly does a package go from active development to non-active development?

Comment: Probably means the package is no longer in active development? ;)

Comment: @Bartek - Well sure.  But what does non-active development mean?  :-)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this Jason. I'm quite curious as well.

Comment: Labels "active"/"non-active" and "development" are unrelated and refer to different things. I believe Development means the package is not installed inside site-packages but it has a link to another location (e.g. an egg-link file).

Answer (score 5):

Looking through yolk source I found this:
***"The following options show information about installed Python packages. Activated packages are normal packages on sys.path that can be imported. Non-activated packages need 'pkg_resources.require()' before they can be imported, such as packages installed with 'easy_install --multi-version'. PKG_SPEC can be either a package name or package name and version e.g. Paste==0.9"**,

for non activated i found:
***'List non-activated packages installed by distutils or setuptools. Use PKG_SPEC to narrow results.'**

and for activated: ***'List activated packages installed by distutils or setuptools. Use PKG_SPEC to narrow results.'**
Hope that satisfies your needs or atleast helps you ;). There seem to be very little documentation on this online.
* found in http://trac.assembla.com/yolk/browser/trunk/yolk/cli.py